# Why does return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); not work if I have a Home controller with Index action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And, route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "spa",
    "{section}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { section = @"home|questions|admin" });
```

When I use the following, I get an error message:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
```

Can someone explain to me why this does not work and why the following works:

```
return Redirect("~/home");
```

Comment: I believe `RedirectToAction` will construct a url like `http://www.yoursite.com/Home/Index`. I _thought_ ASP.NET would have a default route that matches that url pattern (i.e. `/{controller]/{action}`) but perhaps not. I think the route you define in `MapRoute` only matches urls like this: `http://www.yoursite.com/home|questions|admin/someValueForIdOrNothingHere` (assuming that the pipe character is valid). If you want to avoid ASP.NET routing headaches you should really spend the ~15 minutes reading any tutorials you can find. For instance, http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, there is no route that matches, since the one you have does not expect the controller and the action as parameters. You will need to add a route map like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "spa",
        "{controller}/{action}/{section}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { section = @"home|questions|admin" });
```

or like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "spa",
        "Home/Index/{section}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { section = @"home|questions|admin" });
```

I cannot test at this moment, but I think you might get the idea

more info [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)